# How to check for changing clusters in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, cluster-analysis

I am doing some clustering exercises. How can I check for stocks that change clusters over a period of time? Here is a sample of my data.

```
date    2023-03-01  2023-03-02  2023-03-03  2023-03-04  2023-03-05  \
symbol                                                               
AAPL             3           4           1           4           0   
AMGN             0           2           2           4           0   
AXP              2           0           0           0           1   
BA               2           2           0           4           2   
CAT              2           3           4           3           1   

date    2023-03-06  2023-03-07  2023-03-08  2023-03-09  2023-03-10  \
symbol                                                               
AAPL             0           0           1           2           3   
AMGN             4           3           1           2           0   
AXP              1           1           3           1           1   
BA               4           4           0           0           4   
CAT              1           1           3           1           1   

date    2023-03-11  2023-03-12  
symbol                          
AAPL             1           1  
AMGN             0           2  
AXP              0           2  
BA               0           2  
CAT              4           0
```

How can I check for the maximum number of changes over time, and the minimum number of changes over time? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I check for stocks that change clusters over a period of time?", in your example all stocks change clusters, is that the answer you are looking for? For the minimum and maximum number of changes, it depends in what format is your data, if you have some dataframe, or Numpy matrix, then you could use some matrix computation for faster result, but regardless you need to check each stock?

Comment: It looks like AAPL changed 8 times in the example I shared. I wouldn't count 0 to 0 as a chance and likewise I wouldn't count 1 to 1 as a change. How can I count these changes?

Comment: In what format is your data, is it something like [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) or do you just have text files like the one you showed in your question?

Comment: It's a dataframe. I copied/pasted the contents of the dataframe into my original post.